# network state DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET

Tags: wireless, dns, firmware

Recently I bought a Hp pavilion 15 Notebook.

Okey the problem is that when I'm on the internet afterba while of being connected, the pc leave receiving the signal of the Modem, and appears this error.

I'm being trying on GNU/Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS, GNU/Ubunyu GNOME 14.04 , GNU/Ubuntu 15.04, and everything appears the same.

I was trying the following comands:

```
Sudo apgt-get --remove purge bcmwl-kernel-source
Sudo apt-get rm /etc/modprobe.d/balcklist-bcm43.conf
```

Boot
Then:

```
Sudo modprobe -v b44
```

And the wired should now be working
And from the internet :

```
Sudo apt-get update 
Sudo apt-get installation Linux-firmware-nonfree
Sudo modeprobe b43.
```

And it doesn't work at all

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'` terminal command.